# solve a coupled PDE system with some discontinuity by a mixed FEM

Tags: finite-element, discontinuous-galerkin

$$
\begin{cases}
u_t=f(u,v,\nabla{v}),\\ 
\Delta{[g(u)v]}=0.
\end{cases}$$
I want to solve the above PDE system by a mixed FEM, that is, $u_t=f(u,v,\nabla{v})$ by discontinuous Galerkin (DG), where $f$ doesn't depend on $\nabla{u}$, and $\Delta{[g(u)v]}=0$ by continuous Galerkin (CG). The key is that **in the true solution of such a PDE system, $u$ and $\nabla{v}$ exhibit some spatial discontinuity/shock but $v$ is spatially continuous.** For this reason, I'd like to solve $u_t=f(u,v,\nabla{v})$ by DG to retain the spatial discontinuity of both $u$ and $\nabla{v}$.

As is known to all, DG was first used to solve $u_t+u_x=0$. Since $u_t=f(u,v,\nabla{v})$ isn’t the standard form of $u_t+u_x=0$, how can I implement the DG scheme here given the complexity of the true solution?

Comment: How is this question different from the one you asked before and to which I have already given the answer that the solution really just satisfies a local ODE at each node point?

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth thanks Prof Bangerth. I'm not sure if this is identical to the old one, so I asked. The discontinuity and the u, v coupling are what I worry about. Don't you think these'll make any difference?

Comment: The equation for $u$ does not depend on derivatives of $u$, either directly or through $v$. So the equation is local.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth many thanks